# Getting images with curl or snoopy class

Tags: image, curl, snoopy

How to get the only images with snoopy class or curl ? I have got the fallowing  html code     `<img src="unique_pic/itemname.gif" border="0">`

What i want to do?
I want to get the all images with are in file "unique_pic" and they are saved as .gif
or i want to get all the images gif from the website.

I need one of those solution please

Comment: Are you trying to get all the images in `unique_pic/` whether they are listed on the page or not, or just all the `gif` files that are on the page?

Comment: I would preffer to get all images that are from `unique_pic/` file on the website but if you know the way to get images from the website but not from the file i would appriciate it too.

Comment: I wrote a `bash` script that uses `curl` to do this a couple years ago, I'll see if I can find it when I get home tonight.